# Status Bar not Docking Correctly in Dock Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I cannot get a status bar to show correctly in my WPF application. The status bar shows outside of the application window instead of on the bottom. I have a DocumentViewer control that, when removed, the status bar shows, but I cannot figure out why.

XAML is below.

```
<Window x:Class="AppX_Viewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppX_Viewer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Legacy Record Search" Height="768" Width="1024" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ContentRendered="ShowWarning">

<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Label Content="First Name: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirst" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104">Ru</TextBox>
        <Label Content="Last Name: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLast" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104"></TextBox>
        <Label Content="SSN: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSSN" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104"></TextBox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnSearch" Content="Search" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnSearch_Click" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnClear" Content="Clear" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnClear_Click" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnDiskStatus" Content="Check Disk Status"  Width="100" Click="btnDiskStatus_Click"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblDocId" Grid.Column="3" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"  Margin="10,0,10,0" />
    </ToolBar>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="icImages" Width="100" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="Gray">
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
        <DocumentViewer x:Name="dvImage" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <DocumentViewer.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="PART_FindToolBarHost">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DocumentViewer.Resources>
        </DocumentViewer>
    </DockPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="1024" Height="25"></StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `DockPanel` should fill the first one. Remove `LastChildFill="False"` and define the `<StatusBar />` element before the second `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Label Content="First Name: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirst" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104">Ru</TextBox>
        <Label Content="Last Name: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLast" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104"></TextBox>
        <Label Content="SSN: " />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSSN" Margin="0,2,0,1" Width="104"></TextBox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnSearch" Content="Search" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnSearch_Click" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnClear" Content="Clear" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnClear_Click" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnDiskStatus" Content="Check Disk Status"  Width="100" Click="btnDiskStatus_Click"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblDocId" Grid.Column="3" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"  Margin="10,0,10,0" />
    </ToolBar>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="1024" Height="25"></StatusBar>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="icImages" Width="100" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="Gray">
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
        <DocumentViewer x:Name="dvImage" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <DocumentViewer.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="PART_FindToolBarHost">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DocumentViewer.Resources>
        </DocumentViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I changed this to the answer. While the other worked, it was a bit hackish. I can't figure why the markup goes there though. I was putting it after the closing tag for the second dockpanel, but before the last closing tag of the first. I thought docking it to the bottom after the second dock panel would be ok. This is quite different moving from windows forms. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try adding the Margin property to your StatusBar.This will move the whole bar to the left.

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="1024" Height="25" Margin="-1024,0,0,0"></StatusBar>
```

Alternatively use Grids instead of DockPanel.

Comment: Well damn, that was simple enough. I've tried grids, but couldn't get the layout properly for this application. Appreciate the help.